# How to flash original firmware of a device?

Tags: wifi, flash-memory

I flashed Tasmota on my wifi boiler switch (the white one with the glass touch panel the uses 'SmartLife' app like the one here: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07PLQHJDW/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_DiCoEbV2ANWMJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PLQHJDW))
 and I want to revert the flash.
Is there a way I can flash the original firmware back to the device?

Answer (score 1):

You can flash the original firmware in the same way you downloaded the Tasmota one. You should have a backup of it. If you used a tool like Tasmotizer, it may have done the backup for you.

It's very unlikely that a manufacturer releases the firmware for its products, unless they are *open* by design.